# Convert this String to NSDate

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Basically what I'm trying to do is convert a `string` to a `date`. The `string` equals the following:

```
let myDateString = "01-53-36-24-75"
```

And this is the format that it's in:

> Days-Hours-Minutes-Seconds-Milliseconds

So if I wouldn't have the Days, I would just create a `dateFormatter`, and do the following:

```
let separator = "-"
self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH\(separator)mm\(separator)ss\(separator)SS"
```

Then I would convert `myDateString` to a `date` from `self.dateFormatter`. But now that I have days, (the days elapsed,) I don't know how to convert the `string - myDateString` to a `date`.

Comment: If you want the number of days elapsed, then what is your starting date? exp. How many days elapsed since when?

Comment: I have a date I have in my code. If you want I can post it.

Comment: I think you are not using the right tool here — `NSDateFormatter` is for formatting actual dates (points in time). If you want to calculate time/date differences then you should use other things (not formatters). You should also be precise about what you want to calculate — do you mean 3 calendar days (from 31st Aug to 2nd Sep)? Do you mean the total numbers of seconds difference divided by the number of seconds in 24 hours...?

Comment: Learn how to build a date format string.  http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns (Hint:  See "Modified Julian day")  You will, of course, not end up with a "real" NSDate object, unless you add in your "epoch" date.

Comment: Maybe adding an explicit example of the given string, a given reference date and the expected result, could make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to support a date format of:

```
Days-Hours-Minutes-Seconds-Milliseconds
```

Then you would need to have a format like this:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "DDD-HH-mm-ss-SS"
```

The **DDD** indicates that you want the *day of the year*.

---

To get the **date** object from `dateFormatter` (which, let's assume, is an `NSDateFormatter` instance) then you would use the `dateFromString` method. For example:

```
var myDate: NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString("01-53-36-24-75")
```

Note that [dateFromString](http://atter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString:) returns an Optional. Thus, if your format can't convert the given string then `nil` is returned.

---

Now, there are two things I want to point out.

**First**, that date format **does not provide** a year value. Therefore, the year value will be a default year.

**Second**, the date string `01-53-36-24-75` seems wrong. Specifically, the hours value of `53` is out of bounds (it should be a max of 23).

At any rate, if you run this snippet of code:

```
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "DDD-HH-mm-ss-SS"

    let myDateString1 = "01-53-36-24-75" // Your value
    let myDateString2 = "01-01-02-03-04" // My example value
    println("myDateString1 = \(dateFormatter.dateFromString(myDateString1))")
    println("myDateString2 = \(dateFormatter.dateFromString(myDateString2))")
```

The console output would be:

```
myDateString1 = nil
myDateString2 = Optional(2000-01-01 06:02:03 +0000)
```

As you can see, your value converted to `nil` because the `53` couldn't be converted.

My value's year value converted to `2000`, a default because it doesn't have a year specified in the format or the string.

---

See this [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for the symbols used in date formatters. (This link was referred to by the Apple's [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) page.)

Comment: You're right about the 1 day and 53 hours. I was just giving an example of the numbers and I wasn't thinking.

Comment: If I did not get it wrong, components from the string refers to an already given date. Thus `NSDateFormatter` might not be the right tool.

Comment: @Jessica Ok, I understand about the 53. :) By the way, I updated my post to make clear about how you would get an actual NSDate object back from the NSDateFormatter. Is this what you are asking? Does that make sense?

Comment: @MatteoPiombo  `NSDateFormatter` is capable of converting a formatted date string into an `NSDate` object. See the `dateFromString` method. Also, see my code snippet in my post. You can run it and try. :)

Comment: @whyceewhite sure it is ... but read the comment. As I get it 1 day means 1 day starting from a given date. Thus if the given date is today, it should give you tomorrow. `NSDateFormatter` does not do date calculations from an arbitrary date.

Comment: @MatteoPiombo Aaaahhh.... So you're saying that the date string represents the day, hours, seconds, minutes and milliseconds that have elapsed. And, that value should be added to some other date to get yet another final date. Is that true @Jessica? I misunderstood the question completely.

Comment: @whyceewhite That's exactly what I'm trying to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

dd will give you the day.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

would be year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds

Comment: I don't want the day, I want the days elapsed. For example: 3 days since a date to now.

Comment: your question was not clear. You don't need a formatter! Try var elapsedTime = date1.timeIntervalSinceDate(date2) to find the elapsed time (check the reference on what it returns : timeInterval which is actually a double